# Code::Blocks not being able to find standard library headers?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, codeblocks

I recently switched from Bloodshed to Code::Blocks. I wrote a simple input/output program to get a feel for it, and when I tried to compile it I got errors for all of the headers I had included, saying that there was no such directory.

I took a look at the file and saw that the file was saved as a C file rather than a C++ file, how do I change this? (I know this is why because the C++ files I transferred over from Bloodshed work fine.)

Comment: Just rename the file? Also, posting the code might help.

Comment: Try saving it as <file>.cpp instead of just <file> ?

Comment: Should have made it an answer :P

Comment: How can you set comments as answers?

Comment: @trikker: You don't. You delete your comment and re-post the text as an answer.

Comment: @nagul Why don't you post that as an answer? I doubt OP is still around to accept it, but it will remove this from "questions with no answers", and I'll upvote you. If you do, mention me in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @nagul said in the comments, saving the file as `<file>.cpp` instead of `<file>` fixed the `no such directory` error when compiling.